# Ruby for video encoding and convertion backend?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, video, audio, video-encoding

i am working in a project which target it to convert the video formats, audio formats .. encoding stuffs, where sequential images and sound are mixed up and converted as video. Is this possible via ruby back-end ?  I am really looking forward to work with ruby for this so i want to know before starting that is this even possible with ruby or even better if there is already library or framwork for this task ?